# Admin blank but Admin menu showing

Tags: admin, wp-admin

A client website has recently had the issue of a blank admin but the menu is showing. No admin pages appears at all. Just plain ol white, nothing showing in the source code either.
Front end of the site works fine.

Client states that no plugins, themes or WP Core has been updated.

I installed a copy of the site on MAMP (local machine) and the admin works fine. I then installed the site on a server online but the same issue happens.

I have tried the following:

- Deleted all plugins
- Renamed the plugins folder
- Deleted theme, left default theme
- Deleted WP files and used latest WP files

None of the above made any difference.

Can anyone help out with some ideas what could cause this issue? I know that you have no backend access yourselves but any tips would help. The site is: [letitgrowhydro.co.uk](http://letitgrowhydro.co.uk).

Comment: I actually am not accustomed to this problem, but you can also try something like: deleting the site's `.htaccesss` file (it'll be created again automatically); if the site had any cacheing plugin, you can check the db for some cacheing things, and can del/disable those cacheing things manually to get access into the functional admin panel. I'm not sure I'm giving you THE way, but I'm suggesting to try something like this.

Comment: have you [enabled debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: I tried deleting the .htaccess file but still no luck.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the admin screen and menu?  I need a picture to figure out what component is the problem.  I definitely recommend turning on debugging as Milo suggested; and post any suspicious error messages.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/ovjsuittx/ This appears no matter which menu item is clicked upon except the WPECommerce sections. There are some errors when enabling debug. One such error is: Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in /home/hydro/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3551

Comment: Does the blank screen appear for all levels of user - even administrator? Sounds like something has messed up you user capabilities and set you back about 4 years! If administrator can still see normal content then a plugin like *User Role Editor* would help visualize what's going on. Or try it in your MAMP install.

Comment: You might check the PHP versions match too. The [Codex mentions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Switching_to_PHP5) that PHP differences can cause capabilities conflicts (without specifics). If you have MAMP Pro you can match your local PHP version to the site's and see if the error occurs.